# What is the Best Practice for handling multiple Entities that behave identically?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, spring-boot, multiple-inheritance

Because I have multiple entities with unique fields, I need multiple repositories for each one even though each Entity will be handled exactly the same. What is the best way to handle these separate repos without repeating code, minimizing if statements, and avoiding code smells?

Originally I chose for the Service to have a single Repository which would be given from the config file like so.

```
@Bean
    public StatsRepository<?> repository(League league) {
        if (league.equals(League.CHAMPIONS)) {
            return champRepository;
        } else if (league.equals(League.PSD)) {
            return psdRepository;
        }
        throw new BadInput("The given league is not valid");
    }
```

So inside my Service I have this `StatsRepository repository` field but IntelliJ is complaining about my *Raw Use of the Parameterized Class* and each repo call is flagged as an unchecked assignment. My class goes red if I add a <?> because *Inferred Type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound*.

Is there a better way for me to handle this that does not have any code smells?

I was thinking about Parameterizing my Service like so

```
public class RotoService<T extends Stats> {
    private StatsRepository<T> repository;
```

but then I have to cast all my repository calls from `T` to `Stats` and I think I prefer my former, simpler approach.

(edited to be shorter)

Comment: Why not use ChampsRepository in your RepositoryConfiguration class?

Comment: If both ChampStats and PsdStats behave the same, why does your application even need to know those sub classes exist? They should be using them through the abstract Stats class.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I am using Stats throughout, the exception being the repository calls. And is there a difference between ChampRepository and StatsRepository<ChampStats>?

Comment: Originally my choice was the raw use of StatsRepository in my Service. However, Intellij is complaining about the field and each of my repository calls because of 'Unchecked assignment'. My question is- If that's not the best way then what is? Is there a strategy I can use that won't have any code smells?

Comment: This question is framed as a design problem, but more and more it seems like a coding problem. You don't need to resolve every little warning that an IDE produces. Compiler errors, certainly should be fixed, but IDEs like to suggest things, and it is up to you whether or not you follow their suggestions.

Comment: but why do you need two separate classes if they are identical?

Comment: @GregBurghardt How is it a coding problem? I agree that its trivial, which is probably why I couldn't find anything on best practices pertaining to it, but its a question about which design is the best choice for this working code.

Comment: @user253751 They have unique private fields but all interactions with these Pojos are done via the same public method which returns a List<Double> of the private fields. All of these lists will be handled the same no matter the length or the value of the Lists.